# Договоры или Договора

Tags: орфография

Как правильно будет:
Договоры контрагентов или Договора контрагентов?

Comment: При следующем обращении к форуму поищите в поисковике вас интересующее слово .

Answer (score 0):

В книжной речи: договОр - договОры, в разговорной речи: дОговор - договорА.

В первом варианте ударение постоянное во всех формах слова, во втором  смещается с основы на окончание (во множественном числе).

Comment: При ответе на вопрос поинтересуйтесь через поисковик об имеющихся там положительных ответах на заданную тему.

Comment: Я думаю, что  повторы в первую очередь должны отслеживать задающие вопросы и модераторы (для это у них есть специальные возможности).  В любом случае, комментарий звучит невежливо,  особенно "поинтересуйтесь". Возможная замена: обратите, пожалуйста, внимание...

Comment: «Отвечайте на хорошо заданные вопросы!» Так говорит одно из правил этого форума. Ваш ответ, будь он даже замечательный, спровоцирован «нехорошим» вопросом. Однако же, невнимание — Ваше, а время, потраченное на спец. операции — вежливых модераторов. Берегите его! Помните, как говорила известная всей стране кассирша? — Вас много, а у меня один палец.

Comment: У системы очень строгие требования к отвечающим (как будто они наемные работники по контракту), а ведь они всего лишь совершенно бескорыстно хотят поделиться своими знаниями.  И хотя бы на вежливость со стороны системы могут рассчитывать.

Comment: Ну просто слёзы льются, капают... Бескорыстность должна, наверное, сопровождаться чувством самосохранения  Помните, как далее по тексту? — «Не давай себя хватать там, моя лапочка».